# Accessibility DialogFragment does not focus title but reads out title followed by text

Tags: android, talkback, accessibility

I am trying to fix an accessibility issue in Android using TalkBack service. Found the issue of content description, where [title is being read-out even when content description is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169273/accessibility-dialog-dialogfragment-reads-text-instead-of-content-description). But my issue is text gets highlighted but title is read out. Please find the screenshot with accessibility focus and talk-back text toast. Any suggestions how to fix the focus issue?

[image]

Comment: Seems to be issue in Android Talkback Service.

Comment: How is this dialog created? Could you share the code, or an example?